# How can I convince that an answer is "not an answer"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, not-an-answer, specific-answer

How can I convice that this answer is "not an answer"

The discussion thread in question is [Java, selenium ; How to get text in alt=“  text”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956203/java-selenium-how-to-get-text-in-alt-span-class-forthetest-text-span)

The question reads as :

[image: question]

The answer reads as :

[image: answer]

As you can observe the answer contains the same *HTML* just like the *HTML* within the question with *snippet* markup without any additional content. So, I decided to raise the *"not an answer"* flag which was declined by *Review Team*  with a comment :

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

This forced me to raise *"in need of moderator intervention"* flag which was declined with a comment :

> declined - yes, it looks different from the question. this is an answer but a very poor one. use your comments and downvotes instead.

So, I decided to raise the *"in need of moderator intervention"* flag again with a clarification as :

> No, the Answer part is not different from the question. Code (read as HTML) provided in Answer is already there within the Question.

which was declined again with a comment :

> declined - This is not identical code. The answerer (though they may be wrong), is attempting to fix the syntaxed used by the asker.

But I had known the *Answer* space was to be used only **for answers** but not to *to fix the syntaxed used by the asker*

As per the discussion in [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) the Answer in our discussion seems to be falling in *Asking for clarifications* category.

Did I misunderstand the functionality of the *Answer Section*?

Comment: You are not doing a very good job communicating your intentions here either. You keep insisting that the answer contains the "same" markup as in the question, but they have clear differences. One might even assume you were either looking at the wrong Q&A, or trolling. We generally don't like users repeatedly flagging the same thing if they can't communicate their intentions properly.

Comment: Nothing in that answer that a downvote can't fix

Answer (score 13):

The most recent decline was mine.

As has been mentioned multiple times, this is *not* the same code found in the question.

This answer is pretty clearly attempting to provide an answer to the question. When I wrote that they're fixing the syntax (sorry for the typo, there) of the question - it was implied that they believed the *syntax* was the cause of the issue.

Their answer may not be what the OP is looking for, but it's still an attempted answer. An incorrect answer is not a valid reason to flag as NAA, nor is it valid to follow up with custom flags.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Allow me to disagree that the _markup_ provided in the Answer was attempting to provide an answer to the question. The _markup_ is of the reference _HTML_ to which OP was refferring in his/her question and doesn't resembles as an Answer. It always appeared to me to fit the case of **a comment** among the several clauses of _not an answer_.